# Gitlab Exclude overwrite of certain files during Merge Requests

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Our feature branches are based off of "Dev" branch. the Dev branch is Deployed to development Environment on a daily basis based on our instructions defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml` on dev branch.

When a feature branch is created and commits were made, they are being deployed as feature branch `.gitlab-ci.yml` is same as on Dev branch. if we disable the deploy step on feature branch and forget to uncomment it during a merge request back to dev branch, dev branch will have the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file overwritten by feature branch.

Is there away to keep Dev `.gitlab-ci.yml` untouched though merge requests from any feature branches?
I found `.gitattributes` may help but cannot find a starting point on how to define and use it.

Comment: Why are you commenting out parts of you pipeline in the feature branch? you could just define a seperate deploy step for your feature branches.

Comment: How do we identify feature branch vs dev or master...secondly.. I don't want an intermediary step to comment or uncomment a section in a file as to avoid human error.xan you please elaborate on how to use this additional step for feature branches??

Comment: The file can contain appropriate configuration to handle different branches and scenarios. Have a look at [`workflow`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#workflow) and [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules).

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely simplified example how you could define two seperate deploy steps in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` with [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules). It is based on the assumption that you prefix your feature branches e.g. with `feature`.

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:feature:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy feature branch"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature/'

deploy:dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy to development"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works in the deploy stage of the CI.yml file

```
deploy:
 stage: deploy
 only:
  - dev
  - master
 script:
  - dotnet build -c Release
  - dotnet publish -c Release
```

So the pipelines only run when something is merged on to Master or dev branches. This sounded simpler.